# DataPower and Web Application Resources

Tags: web, httpserver, ibm-datapower

Dears,

I have this question, our `client` requests to make `datapower` acting like `http server` , so i created `multi-protocol gateway service` , and i set the `backend` `http://myLiferayWebApp/` and i set both `request` and `response` types `pass Thru`.

the web application runs successfully but when enspecting elements for `HTML` page i found that all `URL resources` are wrtitten by `datapower` , `javascript` files, `images` and `css` files, like

```
http://datapowerURL:8001/css/header.css
http://datapowerURL:8001/css/footer.css
http://datapowerURL:8001/css/content.css
//-- dozens of css files are below
http://datapowerURL:8001/js/dojo.js
http://dataPowerURL:8001/js/foo.js
//--dozens of Javascript files are below.
//-- the same thing with images ... for every class for every button.
```

so all of these `resources` are requested through datapower ??? is that right to do this with `datapower` and the `datapower` can handle all `resources` requests ????? and can this step affects on performance and speed ????

Comment: Hm, wasn't that what you wanted? Surely it can affect performance and speed (depending on your definition of "affects") but why would you use datapower as http server and then continue routing all requests to resources "around" it?

Comment: Hi @StefanHegny , Actually not me, we have developed `Mobile First App` to the `client`, and `HTTP server` is recommended , the client baught datapower and `IBM` recommened to put `datapower` before every thing as cash tables, load balancer and http server.